# Access the state/variables of Contract A from Contract B

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I would like to change a variable of type enum of a contract A from another contract B. I am getting an error. Is it not possible to do so? The error is in the second line of the below code...

```
contract cs{
 ....
........
POD pod = POD(mainContract);
pod.state = st; 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an enum-specific issue: You cannot modify properties of another contract without a setter function, not even public ones as the keyword `public` just auto-generates a getter but not a setter for you. E.g.

```
contract One {
    uint256 public u;
}

contract Other {
    One public myOne = new One();

    function doSomething() public {
        myOne.u = 123; // doesnt work!
    }
}
```

Instead, you need a setter function:

```
contract One {
    uint256 public u;

    function setU(uint256 _u) public {
        u = _u;
    }
}

contract Other {
    One public myOne = new One();

    function doSomething() public {
        myOne.setU(123);
    }
}
```

In case of an enum this translates to:

```
contract One {
    enum e { ZERO, ONE, TWO }
    e public myE;

    function setE(e _newE) public {
        myE = _newE;
    }
}

contract Other {
    One public myOne = new One();

    function doSomething() public {
        myOne.setE(One.e.ONE);
    }
}
```

[ This was actually interesting, the enum fields (`ZERO`, `ONE`, `TWO` in my example) are exposed to that other contract, thanks for asking :-) ]